# What does the Java compiler error message "<identifier> expected" mean?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
class if{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        int x = 9;
        if (x <= 9){
            System.out.println("Yay");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Yay");
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm running this from the compiler, using Notepad++ as the text editor. And I am getting an error in the compiler saying `<identifier> expected class if`. And another error saying `illegal start of expression`.
  As well as saying `error ";" expected`. I have a total of 9 errors.

I made sure to match all the `{}` and `()`. Even scraped the program and tried again with the same results.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you posted the exact compiler errors.

Comment: Check the Java Language Keywords : http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`if` is a reserved keyword in Java (as seen in your `if` statement), and is thus not an eligible class name.  Choose another name for your class, like `IfTesting`.

By convention, all class names start with an upper-case letter.  The full details for what is and isn't a valid Java identifier are found in the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#40625).  In short, it can't be a [keyword](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html), `true`, `false`, or `null`.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the link. I'll accept the answer when I can. Pointing out that I used if in my program should of been a dead giveaway for me.

Comment: I've forgot to give one of my parameters an identifier... but the error referred to the line with `class` (earlier in the code) instead. nevertheless this QA helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call a class "if". It's a reserved Java keyword (that you're using in your program, BTW).

Furthermore, by convention, all classes start with an uppercase letter in Java.

Comment: I had a feeling it was going to be something very simple. Well, now I know what not to do. And of course feel incredibly dumb,  o well. Thanks

Comment: @Tarrant No reason to feel dumb! We were *all* beginners once. You make mistakes and you learn from them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot name your class or even a variable with a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can't name your class if, as it's a keyword.  Check [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it's (String[] args)

Not (String args[])

Comment: It is the same, just different way to call the function.